# Can not reset stateChangeStart listener

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In the root of my app I have the following listener to check for Authentication/

```
  $rootScope.setStateChangeDefault = function(){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
      ... check User Authentication
    });
  }
  $rootScope.setStateChangeDefault();
```

Then, in the controller for a page that the user must save, I have the following:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
  if($scope.form.modified){
    var response = confirm('Are you sure you want to exit without saving?');

    if(response){
      $rootScope.setStateChangeDefault();
      $state.go(toState,toParams);
    }else{
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  else{
    $rootScope.setStateChangeDefault();
    $state.go(toState,toParams);
  }
});
```

When the form data is dirty, the user is asked if they want to save. That part works. However $root.setStateChangeDefault does nothing in the controller. It is supposed to set the original callback and then try to set the state again, but instead, the user is given the prompt every time they try to change state from that point on. Why is the callback not set back to the default like it is on initialization?

Answer (score 3):

There are few essential issues. These are so crucial, that they could lead to memory leaks.

I created [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UiNEh3kj0ew7TbC0i1Pm?p=preview)

Firstly, I am not sure about the **`setStateChangeDefault()`**. In case we need to hook on the `$stateChangeStart`, we should do it just like this

```
$rootScope.setStateChangeDefault = function() {
  // here we should not repeat to add listener
  //$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
  // ... check User Authentication
  //});
}
$rootScope.setStateChangeDefault();

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
  // ... check User Authentication
});
```

Other words, we should add listener only once. Not inside of a method, which is called over and over again

Secondly, we definitely **MUST** take the return value of the `$rootSocpe.$on()` registration if we do call it inside of controller. Controller is instantiated over and over again - and that means that `$rootSocpe.$on()` is called again and again. To avoid adding so many listeners, and creating memory leaks, we **have to remove them**:

```
// We MUST take this UN-Registration function reference
var removeIt = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'
  , function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
     // content of this is discussed below
});

// and call it on controller destroy
$scope.$on('$destroy', removeIt);
```

Finally, this should be the content of the `$on` - **no** `$state.go()`. Just prevent default or let it continue:

```
  var removeIt = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'
  , function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    if ($scope.form.$dirty) {
      var response = confirm('Are you sure you want to exit without saving?');

      if (response) {
        $rootScope.setStateChangeDefault();
        //$state.go(toState,toParams);
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    } else {
      $rootScope.setStateChangeDefault();
      //$state.go(toState,toParams);
    }
  });
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UiNEh3kj0ew7TbC0i1Pm?p=preview)

Comment: is there a way to disable the listener event after the scope is destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

Because I was altering the `$rootScope` object, I was having to try to find a way to reset the default behavior. For what I was trying to accomplish, it seems that the best answer is to use `$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart'`... instead. This has the added bonus of being destroyed when the state changes as well. So the best answer would be:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
  if($scope.form.$dirty){
    var response = confirm('Are you sure you want to exit without saving?');
    if(!response){
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```